# use tkinter for plotting from a specific .csv file

Tags: python, csv, user-interface, tkinter, plot

I am trying to make an interactive program with the user, If the user choose the file with the name 'example.csv' it should plot whatever inside that .csv file, else if,  if the user choose the file with the name example2.csv it will plot the content of that file and with this idea I will continue. However, after I open the file it does not plot anything. any idea on how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Is your dataframe printing in the print(df) lines at all? You get from the user the filepath string, yet it never seems like you use it in your pd.read_csv() function.

Your code currently states:

```
df = pd.read_csv('.csv',parse_dates=['time'], date_parser=lambda epoch: pandas.to_datetime(epoch, unit='s'))
```

I'm pretty sure it should read:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath,parse_dates=['time'], date_parser=lambda epoch: pandas.to_datetime(epoch, unit='s'))
```

It seems like your code is currently trying to read a file named '.csv', which is not 'AttitudeControl_1.csv.'

Comment: Actually I wrote the full path with the filename and not only '.csv',  I just left it like this in purpose to just show the problem. However, I tried to type filepath instead and nothing changed.